# C# outlook addin how to display my own form region

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

i'm beginning to write a outlook addin that if i click some tree node in the explorer tree then display my own form region in the right yellow area.
it shows like the picture. but ,i have no idea.can someone help?
[image]

Comment: You can refer to the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTNaUhg6has

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Form Regions are only supported in Inspector windows, not Explorer (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/creating-form-regions/specify-the-location-of-a-form-region-in-a-custom-form).  You could alternately create a Task Pane with a VSTO add-in, but it cannot cover the Reading Pane or message list.  Another option is to use Add-in Express Form Regions, which can cover the entire Explorer UI (except Navigation and Task Pane areas).

Comment: i have found that , it could be showed user defined form region in another software. i'm checking how to do that.